# How to access functions defined in a different directory in Gnu Octave?

Tags: octave

I have a main program that calls functions to perform a task. However, these functions are in another directory of the main folder (or these functions are in sub-directories).
   I am not sure which commands may I include to perform this task without any errors.

I tried using `addpath()`, `load()`, etc. but I don't know the proper usage, may be that's a reason.

`Maincode.m` (Is a file in directory e.g `/program/example/maincode.m`):

```
% start of code
plot_traction_force(t_cycle,F_trac_veh);
%end of code
```

`plot_traction_force.m` (Is a file in directory e.g `/program/plotfunctions/plot_traction_force.m`):

```
% start of code
function [] = plot_traction_force(t_cycle,F_trac_veh)
% code goes here
end
%end of code
```

The directory view:

```
|-->Program
 |-->example
    |--> maincode.m
 |-->plotfunction
    |--> plotftn1.m
    |--> plotftn2.m
 |-->extension
    |-->vehicle_data.m   
    |-->electric_machine_map.m
```

where `plotftn1.m`, `vehicle_data.m`, `electric_machine_map.m` are functions called by `maincode.m`.

I don't know how to implement this for a number of functions that might be in different directories of the parent directory.

Comment: Did you try `addpath('/program/plotfunctions')`? Here's the documentation to `addpath`: http://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Manipulating-the-Load-Path.html

Comment: Yes, I gave it a try .. it works but there are many files that shall be called in the main function. If I try the same code in MATLAB and use the option of include folder and subfolders .. everything goes quite well . How shall I do this in Octave??

Comment: I've got a solution!

Comment: addpath(genpath(pwd))

Comment: That includes all subdirectories of the current directory. If you're in `example`, it won't find functions in `extension`. So you need to be in the right location for this to work. Please, post your solution as an answer!